# winform mschart hittest not finding legend

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, legend, hittest

I have a charting application that has an overlay function which reassigns the 'from' chart series to the 'to' chart  using this code :

```
chTo.Series.Add(chFrom.Series[s]); //Reassign series to new chart   
chTo.Legends.Add(chFrom.Legends[s]); //Reassign legend to new chart
```

Works great. 
 However, I am trying to implement tooltips for the legends and am running into an issue where  only the first legend in the chart will show tooltips.  When I do a hittest only the first legend is recognized.  All subsequent legends, while visible on the chart, aren't 'seen' to the hittest method.  I'm thinking this is why the tooltips aren't showing as there is no object to trigger the mouseover event for the tooltip.

I have been unable  to find a way to 'expand' the legend area (as detected by the hittest method) to make this work.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement tooltips for you `Legend`? I've tested OK with setting the property `LegendToolTip` of a Series. A `Legend` can be used for many `Series`, so the tooltip should be associated with some `Series` not some `Legend`.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to King King --

The original legend is created in the same method as the chart thus:

```
                //Create the series legend
                chartSel.Series[ySeries.Name].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                chartSel.Legends.Remove(chartSel.Legends.FindByName("Legend1"));
                chartSel.Legends.Add(ySeries.Name);
                chartSel.Legends[0].Name = ySeries.Name;

                //Format the series legend
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Docking = Docking.Right;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table; //.Row;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Tall;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].IsEquallySpacedItems = false;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 7, FontStyle.Bold);
                //chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].TextWrapThreshold = 17; // 19;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Position.Auto = false;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Position.X = 80;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Position.Y = 2;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Position.Width = 18;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].Position.Height = 12;

                //Format series data point value cell
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns.Add(new LegendCellColumn("", LegendCellColumnType.Text, ""));
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[0].Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; //.TopLeft;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[0].Margins = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Margins(10, 10, 1, 1);
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[0].MinimumWidth = 500;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[0].MaximumWidth = 500;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[0].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(120, chartSel.Series[ySeries.Name].Color);

                //Format legend cell spacer
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns.Add(new LegendCellColumn("", LegendCellColumnType.Text, ""));
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[1].Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[1].Margins = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[1].MinimumWidth = 25;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[1].MaximumWidth = 25;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[1].BackColor = Color.Black;

                //Format series title cell
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns.Add(new LegendCellColumn("", LegendCellColumnType.Text, ySeries.Name));
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[2].Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[2].Margins = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Margins(0, 0, 1, 1);
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[2].MinimumWidth = 1475; //1500;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[2].MaximumWidth = 1475; //1500;
                chartSel.Legends[ySeries.Name].CellColumns[2].ToolTip = ySeries.Name;
```

After the series and legends have been reassigned (using the code in my original post) I then set the legend values based on the cursor position located by the following hittest in response to a mouse-down event:

```
                    pt = activePanel.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
                    ch = activePanel.GetChildAtPoint(pt) as Chart;
                    if (ch != null)
                    {
                        HitTestResult ht = ch.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, false);
                        if (ht.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.PlottingArea)
                        {
                            SetLegendValueText(ht, ch);
                        }
                    }

    private void SetLegendValueText(HitTestResult ht, Chart ch)
    {
        //Get the datapoint 'x' index value
        int dpIndex = 0;
        if (ht != null)
        {
            switch (ht.ChartElementType)
            {
                case ChartElementType.DataPoint: //Cursor is on a series line
                    DataPoint dp = ht.Object as DataPoint;
                    if (dp != null)
                    {
                        dpIndex = ht.PointIndex;
                    }
                    break;

                case ChartElementType.PlottingArea: //Cursor is somewhere in the plot area of the chart
                    dpIndex = (int)ht.ChartArea.CursorX.Position;
                    break;
            }
        }

        //Set legend value and legend tooltip
        for (int x = 0; x < ch.Legends.Count; x++) //foreach (Series s in ch.Series)
        {
            if (dpIndex > 0)
            {
                ch.Legends[x].Name = "Legend_" + x;
                ch.Legends[x].CellColumns[0].Text = ch.Series[x].Points[dpIndex - 1].YValues[0].ToString();
                ch.Legends[x].CellColumns[0].ToolTip = ch.Legends[x].CellColumns[0].Text;
            }
        }           
    }
```

So, I end up with the legends looking the way I want them, but the tooltips only show for the first legend item.  I've tried to do custom items as well.  With them I get the tooltips, but I lose the formatting.  This has been driving me crazy for weeks (off and on) and I would really like to move on to other issues.  Clearly (to me anyway), I am not doing something right simply because I don't know everything there is to know about the charts, and the MSChart Samples are of very limited benefit.

I'd be most grateful if I could be pointed in the right direction.